# Azure CDN with blob storage: WebContentNotFound when using Origin Path

Tags: angular, azure, single-page-application, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

We have a static website (angular) hosted in a Azure Blob Storage with a web$ folder and all options set.

See picture below:

[image]
[image]

When we put the website in the root folder web$ of the blob storage, everything works fine.  And when we reload the page, all pages/routes are redirected to the index.html of our SPA.

But we need to host several static sites on the same web$ folder.
So we created folders and set the option "Origin Path" to the target folder for each endpoint created.

We have now:
/folder1/index.html for the first endpoint in the CDN
/folder2/index.html for the second endpoint in the CDN

Everything works fine but not the reload.  As soon as we refresh the page, the endpoint of the CDN doesn't retrieve the target folder.

We have another project where the same configuration is working fine but we found that it is the serviceworker of our PWA which is caching the index.html (not the CDN)
But we need a solution without serviceworker.

Maybe with a redirect rule?

**[Edit] 02-march-2019**

Here is the printscreen of the error when I try to reload

[image]

And here is the configuration **for One of the multiple endpoints we have**:

[image]

And the content of our Web$ folder in our container:

[image]

Comment: This is the solution that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the CDN for every "subfolder" path on your origin path, try to enter `/folder1` or `/folder2` in the `Origin path` field.

For Azure CDN endpoints return a 404 status code, there are several possible causes, including:

> - The file's origin isn't visible to the CDN.
> - The endpoint is misconfigured, causing the CDN to look in the wrong place.
> - The host is rejecting the host header from the CDN.
> - The endpoint hasn't had time to propagate throughout the CDN

You could try the [troubleshooting steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-troubleshoot-endpoint#troubleshooting-steps).

Comment: That's what we did. It works when you load the page, not when you reload the page (F5 with your browser)

Comment: do you have all website files in the same "subfolder"? Could you show the page when you F5?

Comment: I edited my question with all printscreens and information.  All our websites are located in different folders (1 subfolder for 1 website)

Comment: No idea, you may consider using the original blob URL like https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/$web/subfolder/index.html. then change the `origin type` to a storage account and `public access level` to container level and origin path. What's the result? If no luck, you can put 1 container (not inside the $web) for 1 website.

Comment: That's what we did.  1 container for 1 website.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need the Azure Storage static website feature anymore. You can just create a custom container (like your folder1, not as subfolder but as container) and use as Origin Path "/folder1/index.html".
You probably need to set up some rules in the rules engine to make it work properly after reload, depending on your needs.

[image: azure cdn index rewrite rule]

You might also want to have some redirect rules for SPAs like I explained here [Hosting SPA with Static Website option on Azure Blob Storage (clean URLs and Deep links)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072306/hosting-spa-with-static-website-option-on-azure-blob-storage-clean-urls-and-dee)
Andreas